# Spring 5 getting lists of objects from Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-environment

using latest Spring 5 on Java 9....

With the following YAML:

```
flow:
  - name: cats
    url: http://dogs.com
  - name: dogs
    url: http://cats.com
```

With `Environment` the nested property values can be pulled as usual (`env.getProperty("flow[0].name")` to a string).  But how do I pull the **flow** list into an `List<Flow>`?

Assuming I need a `ConfigurationProperties` that maps to a `Flow` class.  Don't want to prefix **flow** in the yaml.

Then via `Environment` what would the call to `getProperty` look like (e.g. `env.getProperty("flow", List.class)` but with the generic `List<Flow>` reference).  As an aside, the reason I want the list of **flows** is to register beans after the environment is setup (i.e. EnvironmentPostProcessor) with the individual **flow** configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Give it a try.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class Configclass {

  List<Flow> flow;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Flow {

  public String name;
  public String url;
}
```

Comment: @pypkiran Didn't know about lombok. Thanks. Setup worked and I autowired in the "Configclass" to get at the "Flow" list.  Still wondering how to cast from env.getProperty to a generic list?